# Google Script Export Spreadsheet to XML File

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, download, google-sheets

I am trying to create a menu button in my Google Spreadsheet that runs a script.
This script should extract specific rows and columns, then export them to an XML file.

I am trying to write the xml file using the ContentService, but it does not seem to work. Is there an example or tutorial that can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you getting any error messages? Or, what specifically is not working?

I've just tested it and it seems fine, here's my snippet

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var content;
  try {
    content = doIt(e);
  } catch(err) {
    content = '<error>' + (err.message || err) + '</error>';
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(content)
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.XML);
}

function doIt(e) {
  if (!e) throw 'you cannot run/debug this directly\nyou have to either call the url or mock a call';
  if (!e.parameter.id) throw '"id" parameter not informed. Please provide a spreadsheet id.';

  var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById(e.parameter.id)
    .getSheets()[0].getRange('A1:B2').getValues();
  return '<sheet>' + values.map(function(row, i) {
    return '<row>' + row.map(function(v) {
      return '<cell>' + v + '</cell>';
    }).join('') + '</row>';
  }).join('') + '</sheet>';
}
```

By the way, I've published this script as a web-app running as the user for anyone to test: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwrctRyspI2LnZ5hP8CMm7yY96jebLQS_4LShaKr_RIUKLm9qg/exec?id=*paste-a-spreadsheet-id-here*

Comment: Thanks! Its working now, the trick was to deploy the script as a webapp.
Thank you again ;)

Comment: this is where i get completely confused with google - it says your scripts want permission to view my docs but obviously i don't want you to (no offence)

Comment: This script does read the A1:B2 range of spreadsheet you provide the id on the url (to generate its xml output). The whole code is available on the answer though. If you don't trust my script (which you really shouldn't), you can copy the code and deploy it yourself.