# Looking to create an XML feed from a Google Sheet Table

Tags: javascript, xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Looking for some help please, I've been tinkering with the code now most of the day and im stuck, and this seems about the best solution I have found so far.

I'm trying to create a script that will create an XML file from a Google Sheet table.

The example sheet is like this >> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tSWMiXBRyhFcAmwpH5tEJiyHCB5vjlGwuHFv865-85A/edit?usp=sharing

I came across this code example [Google Script Export Spreadsheet to XML File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41377818/google-script-export-spreadsheet-to-xml-file) and it's 90% what I need and I got it working via publishing as a web app here >> https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxVcUi6dXw0D1CWfZTlwf94gAT9QjqpG__-SaCIHVFVPzftndU/exec?id=1tSWMiXBRyhFcAmwpH5tEJiyHCB5vjlGwuHFv865-85A

I'm now stuck on getting it to loop over the headers and values as the XML needs to be formatted.

Im also encountering some of the values have attributes, so im finding it tricky to add the xml:lang="x-default" in the below example
10AM : 6PM

Here is an example of what im trying to create

```
<store store-id="F123">
    <name>Store One</name>
    <address1>123 Street</address1>
    <address2></address2>
    <city>London</city>
    <postal-code>L67 9JF</postal-code>
    <phone>123 456</phone>
    <store-hours xml:lang="x-default">10AM | 6PM</store-hours>
    <custom-attribute attribute-id="freeTextTitle" xml:lang="x-default">Store Description Title</custom-attribute>
    <custom-attribute attribute-id="v3_store_open_hours_0" xml:lang="x-default">11 AM|7 PM</custom-attribute>
</store>
<store store-id="G456">
    <name>Store Two</name>
    <address1>123 Street</address1>
    <address2></address2>
    <city>Manchester</city>
    <postal-code>L67 9DS</postal-code>
    <phone>123 456</phone>
    <store-hours xml:lang="x-default">10AM | 6PM</store-hours>
    <custom-attribute attribute-id="freeTextTitle" xml:lang="x-default">Store Description Title</custom-attribute>
    <custom-attribute attribute-id="v3_store_open_hours_0" xml:lang="x-default">11 AM|7 PM</custom-attribute>
</store>
```

Many thanks

** Added more context

Thanks, Both, I'm actually stuck on the JavaScript map() function in the doIt function trying to map the headers & attributes

```
function doGet(e) {
  var content;
  try {
    content = doIt(e);
  } catch(err) {
    content = '<error>' + (err.message || err) + '</error>';
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(content).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.XML);
}

function doIt(e) {
  if (!e) throw 'you cannot run/debug this directly\nyou have to either call the url or mock a call';
  if (!e.parameter.id) throw '"id" parameter not informed. Please provide a spreadsheet id.';

  var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById(e.parameter.id).getSheets()[0].getRange('A1:J4').getValues();
  return '<sheet>' + values.map(function(row, i) {
    return '<row>' + row.map(function(v) {
      return '<cell>' + v + '</cell>';
    }).join('') + '</row>';
  }).join('') + '</sheet>';
}
```

values grabs all of the values in the range, but I'm lost a little trying to break values down.

I did some reading on the map() function so ill have another go

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current issue. In order to correctly understand about your issue, can you provide your script and the detail information of the current issue of your script?

Comment: Use the provided [XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service), give it your best shot, then show us your code.

Comment: Thanks, both, I have added more information where I'm stuck. I'll have another go today

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a simple modification, how about the following modification?

In your script, `<sheet>`, `<row>` and `<cell>` tags are used. But it seems that these are not included in your expected result. When you want to use the header row of 1st row as the each tag, it is required to use them in the script. When your script is modified it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this modification, your `doIt()` was modified.

```
function doIt(e) {
  if (!e) throw 'you cannot run/debug this directly\nyou have to either call the url or mock a call';
  if (!e.parameter.id) throw '"id" parameter not informed. Please provide a spreadsheet id.';
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById(e.parameter.id).getSheets()[0].getRange('A1:J4').getValues();

  // I modified below script.
  var header = values.shift();
  return values.reduce((s, r) => {
    r.forEach((c, j, a) => {
      s += j == 0 ? `<${header[j]}="${c}">` : `<${header[j]}>${c}<\/${header[j].split(" ")[0]}>`;
      if (j == a.length - 1) s += `<\/${header[0].split(" ")[0]}>`;
    });
    return s;
  }, "");
}
```

#### Result:

Whe above modified script is run, the following result is obtained.

```
<store store-id="F123">
   <name>Store One</name>
   <address1>123 Street</address1>
   <address2 />
   <city>London</city>
   <postal-code>L67 9JF</postal-code>
   <phone>123 456</phone>
   <store-hours xml:lang="x-default">10AM | 6PM</store-hours>
   <custom-attribute attribute-id="freeTextTitle" xml:lang="x-default">Store Description Title</custom-attribute>
   <custom-attribute attribute-id="v3_store_open_hours_0" xml:lang="x-default">11 AM|7 PM</custom-attribute>
</store>
<store store-id="G456">
   <name>Store Two</name>
   <address1>124 Street</address1>
   <address2 />
   <city>Manchester</city>
   <postal-code>L67 9DS</postal-code>
   <phone>124 111</phone>
   <store-hours xml:lang="x-default">9AM | 5PM</store-hours>
   <custom-attribute attribute-id="freeTextTitle" xml:lang="x-default">Store Description Title</custom-attribute>
   <custom-attribute attribute-id="v3_store_open_hours_0" xml:lang="x-default">12 AM|7 PM</custom-attribute>
</store>
<store store-id="J542">
   <name>Store Three</name>
   <address1>777 High Street</address1>
   <address2 />
   <city>Leeds</city>
   <postal-code>L7 9GG</postal-code>
   <phone>555 222</phone>
   <store-hours xml:lang="x-default">10AM | 6PM</store-hours>
   <custom-attribute attribute-id="freeTextTitle" xml:lang="x-default">Store Description Title</custom-attribute>
   <custom-attribute attribute-id="v3_store_open_hours_0" xml:lang="x-default">12 AM|7 PM</custom-attribute>
</store>
```

#### Note:

- When you use above result as the xml data, for example, I think that it is required to enclose like `<contents>{above results}</contents>`. Please be careful this. So if you want to export the valid XML data, please use the following script. In this case, `<contents>` is a sample tag.

  ```
    function doIt(e) {
      if (!e) throw 'you cannot run/debug this directly\nyou have to either call the url or mock a call';
      if (!e.parameter.id) throw '"id" parameter not informed. Please provide a spreadsheet id.';
      var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById(e.parameter.id).getSheets()[0].getRange('A1:J4').getValues();

      // I modified below script.
      var header = values.shift();
      var data = values.reduce((s, r) => {
        r.forEach((c, j, a) => {
          s += j == 0 ? `<${header[j]}="${c}">` : `<${header[j]}>${c}<\/${header[j].split(" ")[0]}>`;
          if (j == a.length - 1) s += `<\/${header[0].split(" ")[0]}>`;
        });
        return s;
      }, "");

      return XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(XmlService.parse(`<contents>${data}$</contents>`));
    }
  ```
- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- Please use this script with enabling V8.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Tanaike you are an absolute star! It works exactly how I hoped.

I would have never got to that result, im trying to reverse the JavaScript to see how you did it.

If only I could buy you a beer :)

Thank you

Comment: @James Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand about your question by your cooperation. Thank you, too.

Comment: I added `var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById(e.parameter.id).getSheets()[0].getRange('A1:J4').getValues();` because I noticed my copy and paste mistake.