# Creating an xml file with a script from google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good day to all.
You need to create an xml file with a script from google spreadsheets.
I use the code from these two topics:

[Google Script Export Spreadsheet to XML File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41377818/google-script-export-spreadsheet-to-xml-file)

[Looking to create an XML feed from a Google Sheet Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63473811/looking-to-create-an-xml-feed-from-a-google-sheet-table)

As a result, I get this error, people, what am I doing wrong, please help

As a result, the error '"id" parameter not informed is shown. Please provide a spreadsheet id.'; Please tell me how to correctly substitute the id of the desired table correctly.

I am attaching a link to the table with the output data and an example of the xml that should be the result

```
<offer available="true" id="1">
<price>12</price>
<currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
<categoryId>100</categoryId>
<name>Name 1</name>
<stock_quantity>10</stock_quantity>
<description>Desc desc</description>
<param name="char1">Char1_1</param>
<param name="char2">Char2_1</param>
<param name="char3">Char3_1</param>
</offer>
```

Table:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w3tRBG6WgpomOVGkDN0Sa0fB7gATtrWm2EsRv4zEOWI/edit?usp=sharing

thanks for answers Really really needed

Comment: First, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. And also, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your situation from `As a result, the error '"id" parameter not informed is shown. Please provide a spreadsheet id.';`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the detail of your question?

Comment: Please share a miunimal reproducible example and your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function myXML() {
  const [headers, ...rows] = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  let xmlString = ''
  rows.forEach((r, i) => {
    xmlString += `<${headers[0]}="${r[0]}">\n`
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      if (j != 0) { xmlString += `\t<${headers[j]}>${c}</${headers[j]}>\n` }
      if (j == (headers.length-1)) { xmlString += `</${headers[0]}>\n` }
    })
  })
  console.log (xmlString)
}
```