# Google script not web app for XML creation

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Would someone be able to help me [make the script @Mike Steelson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72683557/creating-an-xml-file-with-a-script-from-google-spreadsheet) made in his reply to a question instead of the first column show up as the XML child element name become a tag in the child element plus make a root element name and child element name of my choice? It works great otherwise but I need that control on the structure of the outputting of the XML. It will need to iterate over 1200 rows as well. I am also not sure how to get it to spit out the file so I can get a copy of it. It needs to spit XML in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<student-details xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <studentRecord>
         <column header name>cell content</column header name>
         <column header name>cell content</column header name>
         <column header name>cell content</column header name>
         <column header name>cell content</column header name>        
     </studentRecord>
</student-details>
```

I am not sure if it should be a Web App or how to make a Web App if needed so any helpful pointers on this would be helpful.

Here is [my Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18GG2xMGWcYXydIBHnyG0U3YTsK0dXhqP5HPiBWgc8xI/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const [headers, ...rows] = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  const root = XmlService.createDocument();
  const n = XmlService.getNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
  const studentDetails = XmlService.createElement("student-details").setNamespace(n);
  rows.forEach(r => {
    const studentRecord = XmlService.createElement("studentRecord");
    headers.forEach((h, j) => {
      studentRecord.addContent(XmlService.createElement(h).setText(r[j]));
    });
    studentDetails.addContent(studentRecord);
  });
  root.addContent(studentDetails);
  const res = XmlService.getRawFormat().format(root).replace(/<\?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"\?>/, `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`);
  console.log(res);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run with your provided Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsi:student-details
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <studentRecord>
        <FirstName>Person 1</FirstName>
        <MI>E</MI>
        <LastName>Morning</LastName>
        <GradTerm></GradTerm>
        <InstHonrCode></InstHonrCode>
        <DegcCode>Gr. Cert.,</DegcCode>
        <MajrCode1>Teach Cred-Sec Ed</MajrCode1>
        <MajrCodeConc1>Initial Teacher Certificate Program</MajrCodeConc1>
        <MajrCode2></MajrCode2>
        <MajrCodeConc12></MajrCodeConc12>
        <Major3></Major3>
        <Major4></Major4>
        <DeptHonrCode></DeptHonrCode>
        <CollCode1>EU</CollCode1>
        <ConfidInd>N</ConfidInd>
        <GrstCode>Second Audit</GrstCode>
        <GradDate></GradDate>
        <AcyrCode>2024</AcyrCode>
    </studentRecord>
    <studentRecord>
        <FirstName>Person 2</FirstName>
        <MI>D</MI>
        <LastName>Sun</LastName>
        <GradTerm></GradTerm>
        <InstHonrCode></InstHonrCode>
        <DegcCode>Gr. Cert.,</DegcCode>
        <MajrCode1>K-12 Art</MajrCode1>
        <MajrCodeConc1>Initial Teacher Certificate Program</MajrCodeConc1>
        <MajrCode2></MajrCode2>
        <MajrCodeConc12></MajrCodeConc12>
        <Major3></Major3>
        <Major4></Major4>
        <DeptHonrCode></DeptHonrCode>
        <CollCode1>EU</CollCode1>
        <ConfidInd>N</ConfidInd>
        <GrstCode>Second Audit</GrstCode>
        <GradDate></GradDate>
        <AcyrCode>2024</AcyrCode>
    </studentRecord>
    <studentRecord>
        <FirstName>Person 3</FirstName>
        <MI></MI>
        <LastName>Junction</LastName>
        <GradTerm></GradTerm>
        <InstHonrCode></InstHonrCode>
        <DegcCode>Gr. Cert.,</DegcCode>
        <MajrCode1>Teach Cred-Sec Ed</MajrCode1>
        <MajrCodeConc1>Initial Teacher Certificate Program</MajrCodeConc1>
        <MajrCode2></MajrCode2>
        <MajrCodeConc12></MajrCodeConc12>
        <Major3></Major3>
        <Major4></Major4>
        <DeptHonrCode></DeptHonrCode>
        <CollCode1>EU</CollCode1>
        <ConfidInd></ConfidInd>
        <GrstCode>Second Audit</GrstCode>
        <GradDate></GradDate>
        <AcyrCode>2024</AcyrCode>
    </studentRecord>
    <studentRecord>
        <FirstName>Person 4</FirstName>
        <MI></MI>
        <LastName>Moon</LastName>
        <GradTerm></GradTerm>
        <InstHonrCode></InstHonrCode>
        <DegcCode>Gr. Cert.,</DegcCode>
        <MajrCode1>Teach Cred-Sec Ed</MajrCode1>
        <MajrCodeConc1>Initial Teacher Certificate Program</MajrCodeConc1>
        <MajrCode2></MajrCode2>
        <MajrCodeConc12></MajrCodeConc12>
        <Major3></Major3>
        <Major4></Major4>
        <DeptHonrCode></DeptHonrCode>
        <CollCode1>EU</CollCode1>
        <ConfidInd></ConfidInd>
        <GrstCode>Second Audit</GrstCode>
        <GradDate></GradDate>
        <AcyrCode>2024</AcyrCode>
    </studentRecord>
</xsi:student-details>
```

#### Note:

- In the case of the namespace of `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`, the prefix `xsi` is automatically added like `xsi:student-details`. But, if you want to remove it, please modify it as follows.

  - From

    ```
      const res = XmlService.getRawFormat().format(root).replace(/<\?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"\?>/, `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`);
    ```
  - To

    ```
      const res = XmlService.getRawFormat().format(root).replace(/<\?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"\?>/, `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`).replace(/xsi:student-details/g, "student-details");
    ```

#### References:

- [XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service)
- [createDocument()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service#createdocument)